# How to find consecutive count last 3 months count and last 6 months counts

Tags: window-functions, vertica, running-totals

Column names: `Site_key. Billing_date ,Reason_type`

Things to Find:

1. Consecutive count for last 5 months:
2. Last 3 month Count
3. Last 6 month Count

I have to find Consecutive count for last 5 months for a `site_key` based on the condition Reason_TYpe.
There are 4 distinct `Reason_type`:

```
Zero_bill
Same_Units
Units_Deviate
Average_Bill\
```

I need to find for a particular site key say for ex: `3`, `billing_date` is say `20-11-2015`, and  `reason type ='Zero_Bill'`

1. How many consecutive previous scenarios were there were site had Zero_Bill (excluding current month)
2. How many such Scenarios in last 3 months (including current months)
3. How many such Scenarios in last 6 months (including current months)

Sample data:

```
 site_key |    billing_date     | Reason_type 
----------+---------------------+---------------------
        3 | 2015-01-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL
        3 | 2015-02-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_Bill  
        3 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00 | ZERO_Bill 
        3 | 2015-04-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL
        3 | 2015-05-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL
        3 | 2015-06-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL
        3 | 2015-07-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL
        3 | 2015-08-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL
        3 | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL
```

Expected Output:

```
 site_key |    billing_date     | Reason_type            |LAST_Consecutive| Last_3_Months | Last_6_months
----------+---------------------+----------------------- +----------------+---------------+--------------------
        3 | 2015-01-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL           |0               |1              |1
        3 | 2015-02-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_Bill              |0               |1              |1
        3 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00 | ZERO_Bill              |1               |2              |2    
        3 | 2015-04-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL           |0               |2              |2
        3 | 2015-05-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL           |1               |2              |2
        3 | 2015-06-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL              |0               |2              |3
        3 | 2015-07-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL              |1               |2              |4
        3 | 2015-08-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL           |0               |1              |3
        3 | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL              |0               |3              |3
```

What I tried:
For Consecutive count:

```
Select site_key,
       billing_date,
       Reason_type, 
       rank() over (partition by site_key,billing_date,reason_type order by billing_date) as consecutive_count
from schema.AVG_SCN  
where site_key=3 
order  by 1,2;
```

For Last_3_Months and Last_6_Months:

```
Select site_key,Billing_Date,Case when cnt>3 then 3 else cnt end as Count_OF_3, Case when cnt>6 then 6 else cnt end as Count_OF_6
from (
Select site_key,billing_date,Reason_TYPE,count(*) over (partition by site_key order by billing_date) as cnt from schema.AVG_SCN where reason_type='Zero_Bill' group by billing_date,site_key,Reason_TYPE
union all
Select site_key,billing_date,Reason_TYPE,count(*) over (partition by site_key order by billing_date) as cnt from Schema.AVG_SCN where reason_type='Average_Bill'  group by billing_date,site_key,Reason_TYPE
union all
Select site_key,billing_date,Reason_TYPE,count(*) over (partition by site_key order by billing_date) as cnt from schema.AVG_SCN where reason_type='Units_Deviate'  group by billing_date,site_key,Reason_TYPE
union all
Select site_key,billing_date,Reason_TYPE,count(*) over (partition by site_key order by billing_date) as cnt from schema.AVG_SCN where reason_type='Same_Units'  group by billing_date,site_key,Reason_TYPE) as a;
```